# how to retrive single key with value in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Example:
if i give name in my programm i need to get the age with corresponding age also {"Name":"msr","age" :24} like these

```
package mongojava;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class javaconn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); 
        DB db = client.getDB( "admin" );
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("admin");
        DBObject dbo = collection.findOne();
        //String name = (String) dbo.get("Name");
        //String age = (String) dbo.get("age");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("Name", "Siddareddy");
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(dbo);


        BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
        newDocument.put("age", "24");
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
Document doc = collection.find(eq("Name", "Siddareddy")).first();
```